# POST request freezes after add body-parser

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm build vue app, and for mine app need api request to server from client, also necessary proxy any request.

It's mine **vue.config.js**

```
const producer = require('./src/kafka/producer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        setup: function (app, server) {
            app.use(bodyParser.json())
            app.post('/send-message', function (req, res) {
                producer.send(req.body)
                    .then(() => {
                        res.json({result: true, error: null});
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        res.status(500).json({result: false, error: e});
                    })
            });
        },
        proxy: {
            '/v2/order/by-number': {
                target: 'http://address-here'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see so i'm use body-parser **app.use(bodyParser.json())**

After I added it, proxying stopped working for me. Request to **/send-message** freezes after show me error

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request **path-here** from localhost:8080
>   to **http://address-here**

Internet searches have not led to a solution.

Comment: If you call  app.use(bodyParser.json()) then why you added bodyParser.json() as a middleware to '/send-message' route?

Comment: Sorry, forgot remove it.

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint on the producer.send(req.body) line it will never trigger?

Comment: That's right. It will never trigger

Comment: What size of request do you have? By default bodyParser.json() allows up to 100KB

Comment: Seems to be starting to work out.
Me need more time for test. I will report the results later

Comment: It did not help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213188/discussion-between-anatoly-and-mihail-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, i find a solution:
Add second param `jsonParser` to app.post()

See full example

```
const producer = require('./src/kafka/producer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'});

module.exports = {
        devServer: {
            setup: function (app, server) {
                app.post('/send-message', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
                    producer.send(req.body)
                        .then(() => {
                            res.json({result: true, error: null});
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            res.status(500).json({result: false, error: e});
                        })
                });
            },
            proxy: {
                'path': {
                    target: 'http://address-here'
                }
            }
        }
    };
```